# How can I integrate Haskell LLVM passes with C++ LLVM passes (if at all)?

Tags: c++, haskell, llvm

I have a set of custom LLVM passes written in C++. Know I am up to add some new passes with analysis algorithms to be tested. To speed things up, I'd like to write these passes in Haskell. I know that LLVM-hs exists and has a FFI. However, I could not find a way to pass the IR preprocessed by the C++ passes to Haskell and vice versa. Can it be done and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there seem no way to register passes via C interface, there is no way to do it via Haskell either. So the problem is not even in writing a pass in a foreign language, but with its registration.

I think you can achieve what you want by creating a stub pass (say, `HaskellPass`), which would hand a `Module` to Haskell side. You'd also need to compile Haskell code into a `foreign library`, so you can link to it from C++.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. What would be the best way to pass the Module to llvm-hs and from there back to C++?

Comment: It seems you need https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-hs-5.1.3/docs/LLVM-Module.html#v:moduleAST but I haven't figured out how to construct a `LLVM.Module` without `LLVM.Internal.Module`.

Comment: That's exactly the link I am missing. How do I get my module from C++ to Haskell?

Comment: The only way I found is `LLVM.Internal.Module.newModule`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-hs-5.1.3/docs/LLVM-Internal-Module.html#v:newModule

Comment: I guess I will try that. Normally I shy away from everything labeled "internal", but it seems to be the only way. Thank you for your help!